# Add border to CSS Clip path

Tags: html, css

I create this div     `<div class="arrow"></div>` and then drown arrow with clip path using the below CSS code

```
  .arrow {
        width: 40px;
        height: 121px;
        background: #fff;
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
        position: absolute;
        right: -41px;
        z-index: 1;
        top: -1px;
    }
```

but now I face a problem , I didn't need this clip path to fill with background color I just want it to have a border I try to give it `border:1px solid #000` but it doesn't work

Comment: You can't. The whole point of a clip path is that it hides everything outside of itself including borders

Comment: i see a lot of online examples of add border I just cant apply on my code https://codepen.io/bennettfeely/pen/azJWWX/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the codepen example you gave, they have two clip-paths on two divs. This gives the impression of having a border. Modifying it with your path gives you this:

```css
    .arrowLine {
        position: absolute;
        width: 40px;
        height: 151px;
        background: rebeccapurple;
        top:-1px;
        right:-41px;
        z-index:1;
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
    }
    
    .arrow {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;
        right: 5px;
        bottom: 5px;
        background: white;
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
    }
```

```html
    <div class="arrowLine">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
```

The top/left/right/bottom is where the width of the 'border' is.
(You could also use inset:5px instead of writing all of them)

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/darlo/pen/RwMpyeV